# Hypergeometric Distribution2

Tags: probability

From a class of 10 boys and 15 girls, prizes are randomly awarded to 3 children. Let N be the number of boys who win prizes. Construct the probability tables for the random variable N assuming that the sampling is done:

b. without replacement

$$P(N=j)=\frac{\binom{B}{j}\binom{G}{n-j}}{\binom{T}{n}}$$

where

j≤B

j≥n-G

j≤n

N = number of boys who win prizes
B= number of boys (10)
G = number of girls (15)
T = Total (all boys and girls) (25)
n = selections

so we have

$$P(N=j)=\frac{\binom{10}{j}\binom{15}{3-j}}{\binom{25}{3}}$$

Am I getting started in the correct way? For the probability table I would just have 4 options correct? P(GGG) P(GBG) P(GBB0 P(BBB)? Since order doens't matter?

Comment: Yep, your work is correct.  $N \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$, with $\Pr[N = j]$ equal to the last equation you wrote.  Do note that you can simplify the right-hand side and get explicit values for each $j = 0, 1, 2, 3$.